# Applying an S gate on which two states leaves the state unchanged

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, quantum-state

I was going through a guide given by my friend and it had this MCQ which I couldn't get the answer to.

*Applying an S gate on which two states leaves the state unchanged?*

- |0 >
- |+ >
- |1 >
- |- >
- |⟳ >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options:

- just try applying $S$ to each of the states to see what happens. For example $S|+\rangle=(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, so the $|+\rangle$ state does change.
- note that you're effective asked to find the eigenvectors of $S$. So write it in matrix form.

The only thing you have to be careful of is the sense in which I'm guessing "doesn't change" is meant here. Remember that global phases are irrelevant to quantum states, so one might consider
$$
S|1\rangle=i|1\rangle\equiv|1\rangle
$$
as being unchanged.